# Is it better to use .resolve() or .fetch() in discordjs?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

When trying to get user, guild, etc from client.users, client.guilds, is it better to use fetch() or resolve() ? I would like to understand what's the difference between both.

An example, when client is ready I try to get user from an ID, I can with fetch but I can't with resolve. Obviously I use async/await.

```
const user = await client.users.fetch('11112222333344445555')
// or
const user = await client.users.resolve('11112222333344445555')
console.log(user)
```

Comment: `client.users.resolve` returns a `User`, not a promise. `await` doesn't make sense there. Have you read [fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch) and [resolve](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/UserManager?scrollTo=resolve)?

Comment: Okay for resolve. I've read the documentation but I I did not understand where discordjs is going to look for the user object in both cases, I think it could help to understand the difference between the two methods.